# How do i call a function defined in 'methods' in setup?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3

If I am using the setup function to say define a watch in Vue 3, how can I call a function defined in my 'methods' section of the component from the watch? this.fn_name doesn't work, and I can't see where I could find the method in the object returned from getCurrentInstance.

```js
setup() {
  watch(variable, (currentValue, oldValue) => {
    fn_defined_in_methods()
  });
},
methods {
  fn_defined_in_methods() { ... }
}
```

Thanks for any help
(btw, I know I can define functions in setup, but this is not what I want to do)

Answer (score 0):

You're using both Composition API and Options API here? Keep one (CAPI if possible) and after a function declaration like this

```html
<script setup>
function doCoolStuff() {
  doIt()
}

watch(variable, (currentValue, oldValue) => {
  doCoolStuff()
})
</script>
```

---

The `this` keyword is an Options API thing so it will not be available in CAPI (cannot be called inside of `setup`).

Comment: thank you, though as said, im aware its possible to declare functions in setup and do it that way. is there no way at all of accessing 'methods' from setup? everything else seems possible, ie can access 'data' from getCurrentInstance ...